# website and protocol restriction (firewall application)

Tags: firewall

Am developing a firewall application that is suppose to restrict website/protocols/webs directories system wide that i choose

for example

restrict login.domain.com, but not domain.com
restrict domain.com/passport not domain.com
restrict .tld types e.g  .org

pls give me some ideas?

[edit]
Am developing on the windows plat form , from win 2000 to win7, using any vb language vb6 upwards also i want to be able to block any protocol http ftp etc.

Comment: In what programming language do you want to do this? Using what platform? What protocols / access methods are you planning to limit on what level? This is *way* too hazy to answer. Also, are you sure it makes sense to develop an application in a field where there are thousands of solutions already?

Comment: i added some more info, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to investigate developing a SOCKS proxy, this is capable of filtering all protocols. Other avenues you could pursue include developing a Winsock LSP or writing your own routing software (like ISA Server).

You'll be hard pressed to do it in Visual Basic 6 or VB .NET however.

Comment: SOCKS proxy can be system wide with the right software. I have updated my answer to include two new methods you use to implement system wide filtering.

Comment: "You'll be hard pressed to do it in Visual Basic 6 or VB .NET however." which language do i use the?

Comment: You could write a SOCKS proxy in VB6 or VB .NET but for an LSP or your own routing software consider C or C++.